# Center an image in jQuery Mobile

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile

I am attempting to center in image in jQuery mobile using CSS. No matter what styles I apply to the image it will not center. Please not the extremes in the css were to see if the image is even being manipulated but it is not. It remains in the same position. I have tried adding a class to the image itself and aligning it center but that did not work either.

HTML:

```
<div class="me">
    <h2 class="name">John Doe</h2>
    <img src="MyPic1.jpg" alt="My Photo" height="200px"/>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.me{text-align:center;
padding-left: 50px;
margin-left: 100px;}
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/jcn9Lxso/ Your code seem to work fine outside. You might have something modified to that `h2` styling..

Comment: Try making the `<img>` block and add an auto margin: `{display:block;margin:auto;}`

Comment: This worked! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try change your css to

```
.me img{text-align:center;
padding-left: 50px;
margin-left: 100px;}
```

Maybe its just something what rewriting your css. You can try position relative and then give it left: 0; right: 0; and text-align: center;